# Trim HTML5 Video?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have searched Google for an answer but no information was found.
Does anyone know if there is a way to trim an HTML5 video using JavaScript?
Something like setting start point and end point, and then getting a new instance of the trimmed video section?

Is it possible or it must be done on server side?

Comment: you can mimic one if you hide the controls and use a range-input/slider to stretch a sub-section worth of slider to the width of the video box. As far as a true digital video manipulation, not yet, in any sort of a mainstream way at least.

Comment: What do you want to do with the new video? Perhaps, there's a workaround.

Comment: I want to allow the users to upload a video and then trim a section of the video, and play only that section.